# php echo form not work

Tags: php, html

In PHP file in MySQL loop output I put this:

```
echo '<form id="sendxpin'.$id_pro.'" method="post" action="proyect.php" target="proyex'.$id_pro.'">
<input type="hidden" name="idxpin'.$id_pro.'" id="idxpin'.$id_pro.'" value="'.$xpin.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="idid'.$id_pro.'" id="idid'.$id_pro.'" value="'.$id_pro.'" />
<input type="hidden" name="idkey'.$id_pro.'" id="idkey'.$id_pro.'" value="'.$xkey.'" />
</form>';
```

but generated html like this:

```
<form id="sendxpin61" target="proyex61" action="proyect.php" method="post"></form>
<input id="idxpin61" type="hidden" value="1234" name="idxpin61"></input>
<input id="idid61" type="hidden" value="61" name="idid61"></input>
<input id="idkey61" type="hidden" value="Z732D8JGVB11YUOQYK9F61H8E5JNE38CMB5467LGAO" name="idkey61"></input>
```

In HTML generated file input fields are out of form and submit for form work without variables, post vars not work.

Why this string `</form>` is printed before input fields?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works correctly for me.

Comment: Cannot reproduce either, code works fine. See: http://ideone.com/7kKQf0

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
    <form id="sendxpin<?php echo $id_pro?>" method="post" action="proyect.php" target="proyex<?php echo $id_pro?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="idxpin<?php echo $id_pro?>" id="idxpin<?php echo $id_pro?>" value="<?php echo $xpin?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="idid<?php echo $id_pro?>" id="idid<?php echo $id_pro?>" value="<?php echo $id_pro?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="idkey<?php echo $id_pro?>" id="idkey<?php echo $id_pro?>" value="<?php echo $xkey?>" />
</form>
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/U9fPgP

Comment: make the [echo] inside the form elements.

Comment: i make it reverse

?>

<form id='sendxpin<?php echo $id_pro; ?>' method='post' action='proyect.php' target='proyex<?php echo $id_pro; ?>' >

<?php
echo "
<input type='hidden' name='idxpin".$id_pro."' id='idxpin".$id_pro."' value='".$xpin."' />
<input type='hidden' name='idid".$id_pro."' id='idid".$id_pro."' value='".$id_pro."' />
<input type='hidden' name='idkey".$id_pro."' id='idkey".$id_pro."' value='".$xkey."' />
";
?>

</form>

<?php

i obtain same result

Comment: whole script its loaded in div element like this:

<div id="enproyectos"></div>
     <script>
function xenproyectos(){
$('#enproyectos').load('artistaproyectos.php?xid='+xxid);}
xenproyectos();
     </script>

Comment: How did you get the HTML source ?
It's from inspect elements or view page source ?

Comment: Yes, from inspect element.
 
all work fine in all options when i change string form to xform. But when i use form so not work.. its possible that is influence any jquery plugin?

Comment: please copy your page source NOT inspect elements to check it, maybe there is a Javascript code run in the background

Answer (score 0):

use **echo** before every line this works for me

```
 echo '<form id="sendxpin'.$id_pro.'" method="post" action="proyect.php" target="proyex'.$id_pro.'">'
    echo ' <input type="hidden" name="idxpin'.$id_pro.'" id="idxpin'.$id_pro.'" value="'.$xpin.'" />'
    echo ' <input type="hidden" name="idid'.$id_pro.'" id="idid'.$id_pro.'" value="'.$id_pro.'" />'
    echo ' <input type="hidden" name="idkey'.$id_pro.'" id="idkey'.$id_pro.'" value="'.$xkey.'" />'
    echo ' </form>';
```

Comment: echo in every line i get same result, i think that the problem is in other side,

whole script its loaded in div element like this: <div id="enproyectos"></div> <script> function xenproyectos(){ $('#enproyectos').load('artistaproyectos.php?xid='+xxid);} xenproyectos(); </script>

Comment: all work fine in all options when i change string form to xform. But when i use form so not work..  its possible that is influence any jquery plugin? how can i find it?